# How to log the backbutton that comes with the navigationcontroller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I am creating a new view using

```
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

The new view (newViewController) stacks on the top of the previous, and comes with a backbutton. I need to access this backbutton to override it. To begin with, finding out how to NSLog a string when  the back button is pushed will be of great help.

Best, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
I have to make a new backbutton in the viewDidLoad function, and add a selector.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];



    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"myTitle"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(mySelector:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

Then the selector:

```
-(void)mySelector
{

NSLog(@"backButton pushed");

}
```